# Removing dynamic dropdown options after JQuery AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a form that includes a dropdown box.  This dropdown's options are filled dynamically, using PHP, from my database.  When my form is submitted, the row containing the ticketId selected in the dropdown is removed from the database.  What I would like is for, after the AJAX call is successful, have this list repopulate without the row that was just removed.

my form:

```
<form name="transferTicketForm" id="transferTicketForm">
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="ticket_number">Choose ticket:</label>
        <select name="ticket_number" id="ticket_number" class="form-control">
            <?php foreach ($assigned_tickets as $ticket): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo($ticket->ticketId); ?>"><?php echo ($ticket->ticketId . " - " . $ticket->headline); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
         </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="assignTo">Transfer to:</label>
         <select name="assignTo" id="assignedTo" class="form-control">
             <?php foreach($employees as $employee): ?>
                 <option value='<?php echo($employee->userId); ?>'><?php echo ($employee->firstName . " " . $employee->lastName);?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="transferComment">Comment:</label>
          <textarea name="transferComment" id="transferComment" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="doTransferTicketButton" value="Transfer Ticket">
      </div>
</form>
```

my Ajax call:

```
$('#doTransferTicketButton').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'<?php echo site_url();?>ticket_system/transfer_and_comment_ticket',
          data:{
              'assigned': $('#assignedTo').val(),
              'comment': $('#transferComment').val(),
              'ticketId': $('#ticket_number').val()
          },
          success: function(data){
              $target_ticket = $('#ticket_number').val();
              $('#ticket_' + $target_ticket).remove();
              $('#assigned').empty();
              $('#transferTicketOptions').slideToggle();
          }
      });
});
```

Things I have tried:

```
success: function(data){
              $target_ticket = $('#ticket_number').val();
              $('#ticket_' + $target_ticket).remove();
              $('#ticket_number').empty();
              $('#transferTicketOptions').slideToggle();
          }
```

and

```
success: function(data){
              $target_ticket = $('#ticket_number').val();
              $('#ticket_' + $target_ticket).remove();
              $('#ticket_number')[0].reset();
              $('#transferTicketOptions').slideToggle();
          }
```

Neither of which work for what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Which element are you removing by this `$('#ticket_' + $target_ticket).remove();`?

Comment: It's a list item in another table on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your AJAX-file echo the ticket ID when removed. This ID will be passed to the success function. And on successs run:

```
    success: function(data){
        $("#ticket_number option[value=data]").remove();
      }
```

The code is not testet, but i think it would work.

Comment: I would think it should work too.  However, I tried it, and I still have the same data populating the dropdown options as prior to the ajax call.

Comment: Does your AJAX-file (ticket_system/transfer_and_comment_ticket) echo the ticket ID?

Comment: Yes.  I included echo($this->input->post('ticketId')); which would echo back the ticket number that is being removed

Comment: What data is sent to the function? success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }

Comment: That sends the correct data.  After re-looking at the code, I had a typo, and once corrected, it worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear! No problem!